# Appsync/CDK: Add a DynamoDB table name as a parameter to a lambda resolver

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

In Typescript CDK 2 I am creating an AppSync instance and a DynamoDB table.  I would like to modify the resolver glue so that AppSync passes the table name to the lambda resolver as a separate argument.  In this manner I can generate different stacks for different tenants and be assured each tenant communicates with their own DynamoDB table via a lambda.

Currently, I use the following to set up the resolver:

`requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaRequest(),`

and I see that that function is setting the payload argument of lambdaRequest to the default argument [[code link](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v2-release/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-appsync/lib/mapping-template.ts)]:

```
   '$util.toJson($ctx)'
```

Since CdK has access to the table name at the moment lambdaRequest is called is there a simple variation of the payload argument to lambdaRequest that adds in the table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the `appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaRequest()` function with my own function that generates VTL for this purpose.

In my CDK directory, under `lib/vtl_templates`, I created a file `generic_request.vtl` with the following contents.

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "payload": {
        "info": { "fieldName": "${fieldName}" },
        "fieldName": "${fieldName}",
        "tableName": "${tableName}",
        "arguments": $util.toJson($ctx.arguments)
    }
}
```

A typescript function in the CDK source parses this file into a template object, performing variable interpolation.

```js
function createLambdaRequest(
  fieldName: string,
  tableName: string
): appsync.MappingTemplate {
  const vtl_template_string = readFileSync(
    "./lib/vtl_templates/generic_request.vtl"
  ).toString();
  const vtl_string = eval("`" + vtl_template_string + "`");
  return appsync.MappingTemplate.fromString(vtl_string);
}
```

Finally, I attached the MappingTemplate object to the DynamoDB resolver like so.

```js
lambdaDS.createResolver(resolverName, {
      typeName: "Query",
      fieldName: fieldName,
      requestMappingTemplate: createLambdaRequest(
        fieldName,
        dynamodbTable.tableName
      ),
      responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaResult(),
    });
```

Running `cdk diff --all` provides a nice way to inspect the result.